# Using additional methods in the Decorator pattern

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, decorator

In the GoF Design Patterns book's chapter about the Decorator pattern there's an example with GUI controls. Here's an example code in C++ (I've changed it a little):

```
class VisualComponent
{
    public:
    virtual void Draw() = 0;
};

class TextView : public VisualComponent
{
    // ...
};

class Decorator : public VisualComponent
{
    private:
    VisualComponent * component;

    public:
    Decorator(VisualComponent * c)
        : component(c)
    {}
    virtual void Draw()
    {
        component->Draw();
    }
};

class ScrollDecorator : public Decorator
{
    public:
    ScrollDecorator(VisualComponent * c)
        : Decorator(c)
    {}
    virtual void Draw()
    {
        Decorator::Draw();
    }
    void ScrollTo()   // [1]
    {
        // perform scrolling
    }
};

class BorderDecorator : public Decorator
{
    private:
    void DrawBorder()   // [2]
    {
        // draw border
    }

    public:
    BorderDecorator(VisualComponent * c)
        : Decorator(c)
    {}
    virtual void Draw()
    {
        Decorator::Draw();
        DrawBorder();
    }
};
```

The point of the decorator classes is to add new behaviour/appearance/etc... to an object. For example:

```
VisualComponent myControl = new BorderDecorator(new ScrollDecorator(new TextView)));
```

creates a text view control that is scrollable and has a border. Adding a border is invisible to the client - it's a private method (`[2]`) and it's called in the `Draw()` method from the `VisualComponent` interface.

However, in the example the authors also presented (in the diagram) a method for scrolling the GUI control (`[1]`). Now, there's nothing more mentioned in the book so I don't know what exactly that method is supposed to do or how it is supposed to behave. Most importantly, I don't know whether it's public (and part of the class's interface) or private.

Assuming it's the latter case, how would it work? The only methods defined by the `VisualComponent` interface are `Draw()` and `Resize()`, none of which really applies to the task of scrolling the control (usually by clicking and dragging a mouse by the user). I've marked possible invocations with `[3]` but I'm not sure they're right.

Assuming it's the former case, the method extends the class's interface with a new public method and that's the gist of my question. How is the client supposed to call that method? If it's not the top-level decorator (like in our example) it can't access the `component` field as it's private.

So, to summarize - can the decorator classes add new **public** methods? If so, how are these supposed to be called? If not (in which case they can only add new **private** methods), should these methods **extend the behaviour of the object ONLY in a way which fits the behaviour defined in the component interface** (`VisualComponent` in our case)? For example, if the component interface only defined a `Draw()` method, should these new private methods only deal with drawing/appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although nothing stops you from adding a new public method via a decorator, it may not be the best solution. You have correctly noticed that the client won't be able to call the method unless the object is referenced by a variable of the decorator's type.

In [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235796/using-the-decorator-pattern-to-add-public-methods-to-an-object), it is suggested that you use inheritance or an adapter pattern instead for such cases. This sounds like a reasonable solution to avoid the mentioned drawback.